# Assign folder permissions in Outlook 2010 with VBA

Tags: vba, outlook

Morning,

I'm trying to identify a way of updating permissions to an Outlook 2010 inbox and all of its subfolders with VBA.

We have an account with a large amount of subfolders that several new users need access to. To assign each of these manually will take hours and I'm looking for an automated process, as this will be a reoccuring task.

Due to administrator restrictions I'm only able to use native VBA.

Is this possible, or am I doomed to hours of mundane repetitive pointing and clicking?

Many thanks

Pete

Comment: An administrator could grant full access.  a) http://www.adamfowlerit.com/2013/01/17/propegating-user-folder-permissions-on-exchange/  b) https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa996343(v=exchg.141).aspx  c) http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=22427

Comment: Hi Niton, I work for a large organisation and the administrator has things pretty much locked down and won't allow additional access. It's a pain to be honest, but I understand the reason...

Comment: Additional access is not locked down if you can update the painful way. The links describe how an Administrator could grant access when you request it for new people.

Comment: Thanks Niton, I've had a look at the links but I don't have permission to download and install any additional software, and my administrator won't do it due to company policy. So I have to do this manually, which is a real chore. Thanks again for your help, but I don't think there is a solution to this issue. Company policy means I'm restricted to VBA only, and this isn't able to address the issue.

Comment: Check out the workaround described in this [superuser thread](https://superuser.com/questions/650134/change-multiple-mail-folders-permission-at-once-in-outlook).

Answer (score 0):

The Outlook object model (used in VBA) doesn't provide anything for changing folder permissions.

You can use a low-level API - Extended MAPI for accessing permissions. Folder level permissions are stored in folders. You need to get the  PR_ACL_TABLE property value using the IMAPIFolder::OpenProperty method. Or you may consider using any third-party wrappers around that API that simplify the dev process. See [Changes in Outlook 2010 folder permissions not shown in Active Directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21325153/changes-in-outlook-2010-folder-permissions-not-shown-in-active-directory) for more information.

Comment: Hi Guys, thanks for replying. It looks like I need either Remption or C++ / Delphi to resolve this issue. Unfortunately, the powers that be will only allow access to VBA, so it looks like I'll be doing a lot of repetative pointing and clicking in the future!

Comment: Note: I did try creating a DL and assigning this access to a folder, but this didn't work either. Thanks again for all your help.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using VBA, Extended MAPI is out of the question (you'd need C++ or Delphi).

If using [Redemption](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/) is an option (I am its author), you can use its [RDOACL](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/RDOACL.htm) object (returned by [RDOFolder](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/RDOFolder.htm).`ACL` property) to manage any Exchange folder permissions:

```
 set Session = CreateObject("Redemption.RDOSession")
 Session.MAPIOBJECT = Application.Session.MAPIOBJECT
 set Folder = Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderCalendar)

'make sure we get back an Exchange user
 set AddressEntry = Session.AddressBook.GAL.ResolveName("Pete")
 set ACE = Folder.ACL.Add(AddressEntry)
 ACE.Rights = ROLE_PUBLISH_EDITOR
```

Comment: Hi Dimitry, thanks for the code. Unfortunately, my administrator won't allow access to Redemption, so I'm stuck and have to do it manually.